# Asynchronous JS: Button needs to be pressed twice to execute onClick(). The onClick() triggers 2 functions but only one is executed on 1st click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, dagre, react-flow

I have an issue regarding an application that I am working on. I have a button that is triggering 2 function. One of them is a setState which changes the direction of a dagre graph and the other one is a function that `React-flow-renderer` provides and fits (centers) the instance of the graph in the screen. I think it needs to be done asynchronously, as the 2nd function is executed only if I double click the button or if I set a `setTimeOut` to execute after f.ex., 3 seconds. So this works:

```
<Button
  onClick={() => {
    onChangeTreeLayout('LR');
    setTimeout(() => {
      reactFlowInstance.fitView();
    }, 5000);
  }}
>
```

This works after the button is pressed for a 2nd time:

```
<Button
  onClick={() => {
    onChangeTreeLayout('LR');
    reactFlowInstance.fitView();
  }}
>
```

So I was thinking of doing something like the following, so that the 2nd function will execute as soon as the first is completed: But it returns `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'a("LR").then')`

```
<Button
  onClick={() => {
    onChangeTreeLayout('LR').then(() => reactFlowInstance.fitView());
  }}
>
```

Can I please get some help to implement the last one and resolve the error or any other way to wait for the `onChangeTreeLayout` to be executed and then the `reactFlowInstance.fitView()` to be triggered as soon as the first is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using async/await:

```
<Button
  onClick={async () => {
    await onChangeTreeLayout('LR');
    reactFlowInstance.fitView();
}}
```

Comment: For some reason I get a warning: 'await' has no effect on the type of this expression.ts(80007). But it doesn't make sense to get that error honestly. As my code works and if I remove the await it doesn't. Any idea why the error?

Comment: Does `onChangeTreeLayout` return a `Promise`?

Comment: Yes, it does! Should I update my answer with the onChangeTreeLayout function? But yeah, it returns a promise

Comment: If it does that error shouldn't be there, weird